# odeCoverageExclude option in angular.json is ignored in Angular 14

Tags: angular

After upgrading from Angular 13 to Angular 14, codeCoverageExclude is ignored by the test runner. I created a sample project on Github where the issue can be reproduced in a brand new Angular 14 boilerplate, with minimal changes.

Please access this link to reproduce the bug:
https://github.com/vzakharov-rxnt/codeCoverageExclude-issue

Answer (score 0):

I still can see the test-ui.mock.ts has been included into the coverage report.
[image]

Here it's the  angular.json for test.
[image]